# How do I install an app from Windows Store using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I know if I have .appx package file, I can install it via powershell with the `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet.
However, I simply want to download & install Microsoft Store packages by name.

I don't want to have to go to the Microsoft Store page, start fiddler, start the download, capture the .appx file URL and then manually download it so that I can use `Add-AppxPackage`.
(See how Windows OS Hub did that [here](http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/))

That could be fun - but it will be flaky. 
I need a robust scriptable method for managing Windows Store apps.

(There are a few software packages that are only accessible via Microsoft Store.
Everything else I can get via Chocolatey or direct msi download.)

One example that I can't yet script is installation of the **HEIF Image Extensions** (needed to view the image format from iPhones: `*.HEIC` format.

Once I install this from the Windows Store, it shows up with `Get-AppxPackage`

```
PS C:\Tools> Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension" }


Name              : Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 1.0.31053.0
PackageFullName   : Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_1.0.31053.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_1.0.31053.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId       : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : False
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.27810.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : Store
Status            : Ok
```

What I want is the cmdlet: `Download-AppxPackage` so that I can do:

```
Download-AppxPackage -Name "Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension"
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Probably more suited to https://superuser.com/

Comment: I submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17382) on their GitHub.

Comment: Have you tried [winget](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)? It can install soft from Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can now use [winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/) to install msstore apps on windows 10 and 11.
Use `winget search <app_name> --source=msstore` to make a search, and use the id of the app to install and upgrade the app.
For example, to install Netflix:

1. First I made a search with `winget search Netflix --source=msstore`, I see that the app id is `9WZDNCRFJ3TJ`.
2. I install app with `winget install -e -i --id=9WZDNCRFJ3TJ --source=msstore`.
3. I upgrade app with `winget upgrade -e -i --id=9WZDNCRFJ3TJ`.

Answer (score 11):

[store.rg-adguard.net](https://store.rg-adguard.net/) is a GUI for generating direct download links to store apps. Peeking at the source of that page, we can piggyback off them to download the content directly, but using **PackageFamilyName**, rather than **Name** (in your example it would be **Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_8wekyb3d8bbwe**).

```perl
function Download-AppxPackage {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string]$PackageFamilyName,
  [string]$Path
)
   
  process {
    $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'POST' -Uri 'https://store.rg-adguard.net/api/GetFiles' -Body "type=PackageFamilyName&url=$($PackageFamilyName)&ring=Retail&lang=en-US" -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -UseBasicParsing
    $LinksMatch = $WebResponse.Links | where {$_ -like '*_x64*.appx*'} | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=a href=").+(?=" r)'
    $DownloadLinks = @($LinksMatch.matches.Value)

    for ($i = 1; $i -le $DownloadLinks.Count; $i++) {
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadLinks[$i-1] -OutFile "$Path\$PackageFamilyName($i).appx"   
    }
  }
}
```

This is limited to the x64 version, and the path must point to a folder. It will download the package and its dependencies and save them all as *PackagefamilyName*(*n*).appx

Comment: Thanks - this is a good improvement. Not ideal as: a) I have to manualy install to find out the PackageFamilyName - and it may change. And: b) I don't know who "rg-adguard.net" are. I'll accept this as answer as probably best we can do until MS give me the cmdlet I want. They may want to divert users to the store to see ads etc.

Comment: as of: 06/25/2021 this is broken. Download-AppxPackage no longer works

Answer (score 6):

Building further on AJ's Answer. Download any app from windows app store with powershell just supply a url from the store and a path for saving.

## Usage:

```perl
Download-AppxPackage "https://www.microsoft.com/p/dynamic-theme/9nblggh1zbkw" "$ENV:USERPROFILE\Desktop"
```

```perl
C:\Users\user\Desktop\55888ChristopheLavalle.DynamicTheme_1.4.30233.0_neutral_~_jdggxwd41xcr0.AppxBundle
C:\Users\user\Desktop\55888ChristopheLavalle.DynamicTheme_1.4.30234.0_neutral_~_jdggxwd41xcr0.AppxBundle
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.7_1.7.27413.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7_1.7.27422.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement_10.0.19011.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.App
```

## Code:

```perl
function Download-AppxPackage {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string]$Uri,
  [string]$Path = "."
)
   
  process {
    $Path = (Resolve-Path $Path).Path
    #Get Urls to download
    $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method 'POST' -Uri 'https://store.rg-adguard.net/api/GetFiles' -Body "type=url&url=$Uri&ring=Retail" -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    $LinksMatch = $WebResponse.Links | where {$_ -like '*.appx*'} | where {$_ -like '*_neutral_*' -or $_ -like "*_"+$env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.Replace("AMD","X").Replace("IA","X")+"_*"} | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=a href=").+(?=" r)'
    $DownloadLinks = $LinksMatch.matches.value 

    function Resolve-NameConflict{
    #Accepts Path to a FILE and changes it so there are no name conflicts
    param(
    [string]$Path
    )
        $newPath = $Path
        if(Test-Path $Path){
            $i = 0;
            $item = (Get-Item $Path)
            while(Test-Path $newPath){
                $i += 1;
                $newPath = Join-Path $item.DirectoryName ($item.BaseName+"($i)"+$item.Extension)
            }
        }
        return $newPath
    }
    #Download Urls
    foreach($url in $DownloadLinks){
        $FileRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing #-Method Head
        $FileName = ($FileRequest.Headers["Content-Disposition"] | Select-String -Pattern  '(?<=filename=).+').matches.value
        $FilePath = Join-Path $Path $FileName; $FilePath = Resolve-NameConflict($FilePath)
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FilePath, $FileRequest.content)
        echo $FilePath
    }
  }
}
```

This correctly downloads neutral and x64 packages but untested for arm and 32bit systems. the path must point to a folder. It will download the package and its dependencies and save them all as their original file names while avoiding name collisions like chrome.

Comment: as of: 06/25/2021 this is broken. Download-AppxPackage no longer works

Comment: hey @DeerSpotter what package did you try to download? my example still runs on my system

Comment: Thanks, it works. I didn't understand though why this fn downloads multiple versions of the same package. E.g. I tried with https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/p/windbg/9pgjgd53tn86 and it downloaded both `Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2104.13002.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx` and `Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2103.1004.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx`

Comment: @André this script doesn't attempt to version check it just performs the download, you are welcome to share an adaptation that version checks~ I am sure it will be helpful for everyone

Comment: Gist: https://gist.github.com/mavaddat/26146d111abf62f6160b1bd02a392ba8

Comment: $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE does not return the OS bitness, it returns the CPU (hardware) architecture. If you install a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit CPU, it will return AMD64. To test the OS bitness use: $CPU = if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {'x64'} else {'x86'}

Answer (score 6):

```
function Download-AppxPackage {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string]$Uri,
  [string]$Path = "."
)
   
  process {
    echo ""
    $StopWatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::startnew()
    $Path = (Resolve-Path $Path).Path
    #Get Urls to download
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Processing $Uri"
    $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method 'POST' -Uri 'https://store.rg-adguard.net/api/GetFiles' -Body "type=url&url=$Uri&ring=Retail" -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    $LinksMatch = ($WebResponse.Links | where {$_ -like '*.appx*'} | where {$_ -like '*_neutral_*' -or $_ -like "*_"+$env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.Replace("AMD","X").Replace("IA","X")+"_*"} | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=a href=").+(?=" r)').matches.value
    $Files = ($WebResponse.Links | where {$_ -like '*.appx*'} | where {$_ -like '*_neutral_*' -or $_ -like "*_"+$env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.Replace("AMD","X").Replace("IA","X")+"_*"} | where {$_ } | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=noreferrer">).+(?=</a>)').matches.value
    #Create array of links and filenames
    $DownloadLinks = @()
    for($i = 0;$i -lt $LinksMatch.Count; $i++){
        $Array += ,@($LinksMatch[$i],$Files[$i])
    }
    #Sort by filename descending
    $Array = $Array | sort-object @{Expression={$_[1]}; Descending=$True}
    $LastFile = "temp123"
    for($i = 0;$i -lt $LinksMatch.Count; $i++){
        $CurrentFile = $Array[$i][1]
        $CurrentUrl = $Array[$i][0]
        #Find first number index of current and last processed filename
        if ($CurrentFile -match "(?<number>\d)"){}
        $FileIndex = $CurrentFile.indexof($Matches.number)
        if ($LastFile -match "(?<number>\d)"){}
        $LastFileIndex = $LastFile.indexof($Matches.number)

        #If current filename product not equal to last filename product
        if (($CurrentFile.SubString(0,$FileIndex-1)) -ne ($LastFile.SubString(0,$LastFileIndex-1))) {
            #If file not already downloaded, add to the download queue
            if (-Not (Test-Path "$Path\$CurrentFile")) {
                "Downloading $Path\$CurrentFile"
                $FilePath = "$Path\$CurrentFile"
                $FileRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $CurrentUrl -UseBasicParsing #-Method Head
                [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FilePath, $FileRequest.content)
            }
        #Delete file outdated and already exist
        }elseif ((Test-Path "$Path\$CurrentFile")) {
            Remove-Item "$Path\$CurrentFile"
            "Removing $Path\$CurrentFile"
        }
        $LastFile = $CurrentFile
    }
    "Time to process: "+$StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
  }
}


if (-Not (Test-Path "C:\Support\Store")) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Creating directory C:\Support\Store"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\Support\Store"
}

Download-AppxPackage "https://www.microsoft.com/p/snip-sketch/9mz95kl8mr0l" "C:\Support\Store"
```

Modified the script so that it delete old versions and only download latest.

Much thanks to Yorai Levi for the original script!

Comment: as of: 06/25/2021 this is broken. Download-AppxPackage no longer works

Answer (score 0):

I've found some additional tools that I think are worth noting and hopefully may be of use to others who are using Windows Sandbox.

Although I tried to install Windows Store manually inside Windows Sandbox, that failed due to required components being missing, but this project fills in all of the gaps:

```
git clone https://github.com/kkkgo/LTSC-Add-MicrosoftStore
```

In that folder, simply run `Add-Store.cmd` and you will now have an operational Store App on the Start Menu in Windows Sandbox, but it is not complete as a few services have to be started also:

```
# 'config start=auto' is not required on Sandbox,
# but is useful for non-Sandbox environments.
SC config wuauserv start=auto
SC config bits start=auto
SC config cryptsvc start=auto
SC config trustedinstaller start=auto
SC start wuauserv
SC start bits
SC start cryptsvc
SC start trustedinstaller
```

Finally, make sure to log in to the Store with a Microsoft account (press the Profile at top right) after which, you should have a fully operational Windows Store app inside Windows Sandbox.

The project was built for Windows Enterprise LTSC (Long-Term Servicing Channel, designed for Windows 10 devices where the key requirement is that functionality and features don’t change over time) that, like Windows Sandbox, uses a slimmed down set of features, but this project works perfectly on Windows Sandbox. The project installs four components to achieve this:

```
Microsoft Store
Store Purchase App
App Installer
Xbox Identity Provider
```